# Splitting a rectangle into MxN pieces, with target aspect ratio

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, continued-fractions

Note: I have an "okay" solution to this problem (see below), but I'm wondering if there's a better algorithm, since mine is fairly conservative.

### The problem:

We have a rectangle with a some width, height ($W$,$H$), and thus a given aspect ratio $A=\frac WH$.

We want to evenly subdivide this rectangle into $M \times N$ pieces. We want the aspect ratio of each resulting cell to be near some target aspect ratio, $T$. Furthermore, we want the final number of cells to be at most $C$.

For instance, if we have a $300 \times 200$ rectangle, with $T = 1$ and $C = 10$, then the best answer is $M=3, N=2$. If instead we chose $C=3$, it would be $M=2, N=1$.

Graphhically:

[image: Diagram of a 300x200 rectangle, being split into 3x2 or 2x1, depending on C]

### My current solution:

This solution works, but is conservative:

The cells' aspect ratio will be $\frac{\frac WM}{\frac HN} = \frac WH \cdot \frac NM = A \cdot \frac NM$

So, we want $T \approx A \cdot \frac NM \implies \frac NM \approx \frac TA$.

Thus, we want a rational number approximation of $\frac TA$, where $M \cdot N <= C$.

I learned about the `limit_denominator` algorithm ([Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/fractions.py#L219)), which essentially does that, using convergents of the continued fraction, but instead of limiting $M\cdot N$, it limits the denominator to some maximum, $D$.

This is where the "conservative" aspect comes in: I use that algorithm, and choose $D = \lfloor \sqrt{C} \rfloor$. This covers the worst case, where the rational approximation is $\frac{D-1}{D}$ (which would make $M\cdot N$ large). Towards that end, I also flip the input fraction if needed, so the numerator is never bigger than the denominator, which means limiting the denominator also limits the numerator.

Going back to the $300 \times 200$ example, if I use $C=6$, I get $D=\lfloor \sqrt 6 \rfloor = \lfloor 2.449... \rfloor = 2$. This does not allow the $3 \times 2$ split, only $2 \times 1$, which is inferior, even though $3 \times 2 <= C$ holds. I need to increase to $C = 9$ so we get $D = 3$ in order to get the better answer.

Of course, if I wanted to, I could use binary search to find the best $D$ in the range $[\lfloor \sqrt C \rfloor, C]$.

### The question:

Is there a better way?

I feel somehow vaguely as though there might be a way to integrate the "limit to $M\cdot N$" requirement into the `limit_denominator` algorithm, but it does not seem straightforward.

Maybe there is a better algorithm, entirely?

Comment: What does it mean for an algorithm to be "conservative"? What is the difference between "pieces" and "cells"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: "conservative" means that it will sometimes give a worse answer than it needs to. In the algorithm described, this is due to the $\sqrt C$ term - it doesn't need to be that low, but that is the "conservative" choice, since it is always guaranteed to be safe. In the 300x200 example given, that choice results in a 2x1 split (since $\lfloor \sqrt C \rfloor = 2$), when a 3x2 split would be superior and also valid. So, the conservative choice is correct, but not the best answer possible within the constraints.  "Pieces" and "cells" mean the same thing, here.

Comment: OK. Now, do $M$ and $N$ have any independent importance, or is it only the product $MN$ that is relevant to the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, the choice of $M$ and $N$ will determine the aspect ratio of the resultant cells, which we want to be as close to $T$ as possible (while still respecting the $C$ limit). In my example, I set $T=1$, but it could be anything. In the described algorithm, you can see the key relation $\frac NM \approx \frac TA$.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood, I thought $M\times N$ was the *number* of pieces, didn't realize it was the length and width of each piece.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, you were correct. $M$ and $N$ are indeed the number of pieces, in the X and Y directions, respectively. For instance, in the example, with a $3 \times 2$ split, $M=3, N=2$. The width of a given piece would be $\frac WM$, height would be $\frac HN$.